# My html will NOT link to my css?

Tags: html, atom-editor

I'm trying to design a simple page about pets I would like to have. I can't seem to figure out why my HTML won't link to my CSS file. I'm using Atom.

```css
.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
  }

  p {
    text-decoration: line-through;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title> My Website about Pets</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"  type = "text/css" />

  </head>
  <body>


<h1>  Pets</h1>
<h3> Below is a list of descriptions of pets that I would like to have. </h3>




<div class="center">
  <img src="https://s7d1.scene7.com/is/image/PETCO/ball-python-1" alt="Ball Python"
 height="200">
  <p>  A picture of a noodly boi</p>

</div>

<h2>Ball Python</h2>
<p> I would like to have a pet ball python. I don't care what gender it is, but it's name will be Goose.</p>






  </body>
</html>
```

These files are both in the same folder on my desktop.

Comment: Use `./styles.css`

Comment: On line 8, remove the spaces on either side of `=`

Comment: @Huangism that is why I gave a different answer; html assumes relative paths.

Comment: @Penn the space makes no difference

Comment: @Huangism I just clicked "run code snippet" in SO and it displays fine, with strike-through... Are you sure there is even an issue here?

Comment: These code run just fine. I copied your code on my computer and it runs very well....

Comment: @Penn I am not the OP, the code would work here because it is all in a snippet, can't reproduce what the OP is seeing on the snippet here

Comment: Btw the spaces are an issue, it's just that that field is irrelevant, as you are simply setting it to the default.

Comment: **oops** @Huangism

Comment: @Penn The spaces are not an issue. The HTML works just fine with spaces in it. Like Huangism, I can't reproduce OP's error.

Comment: Yeah, Its working on the snippet run, but i'm in atom, and im trying to run the page in my browser, but its not working??? I mean yeah the html is there, but the css isnt showing up. @Kevin, how are you running it? are you just opening the html into a browser?

Comment: He is probably not running it in Atom, have you tried using ./styles.css like the first comment says?

Comment: @Kimblebee, did you try to open from the html from the folder instead of atom? it should work , as it seems no issue

Comment: have u tried `../style.css`? whats the folder path

Comment: @Penn having space after or before the `=` makes no difference, the browser will simply ignore it. It even validates

Comment: Yes, i opened the enclosing folder, and i clicked on the html file and opened it in chrome. Both of the files are in the same folder. The css is not showing up. I tried on both my pc desktop and my mac laptop. i've tred the ./style.css

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + J , what is the console error you are seeing in Chrome browser?

Comment: @Huangism yes, sorry, you appear to be right. And to think that I spent this whole time thinking you cannot have a space either side of the equals... :(

Comment: is the name of the css file styles.css? I don't know what else to ask lol, this code even validates so it must be the naming lol

Comment: I FIXED IT!!! The issue was very simple. it turned out the files i hadd werent saved as .html or .css. I thought it was implied, but really i was just opening the text files. Thank you so much though!

Comment: @Kimblebee for these kind of issues, browser developer tools are best options to debug